# React-Native - How is it possible that when I close an app like messenger I can still receive incoming call notifications from others

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-webrtc

I am building an app like **Messenger**, everything works normally like sending messages, receiving messages, video calling. the technologies i use are **react-native, reactJS, socket.io, nodeJS, react-native-webrtc**

I wonder how can when I close an app like the messenger I can still receive incoming call notifications from other people. I'm studying firebase notification and react-native-background-timer but it doesn't seem to work the way I want it to

Has anyone had a problem like this and have an answer, please let me know
Have a nice day guys <3

Comment: FCM (that you already mention) or [Web Push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API) is what these apps use. --- "it doesn't seem to work the way I want it to" No sure what you mean by that though, so it's hard to help. If you tried to implement these APIs, but can't get them to work, edit your question to show the [minimal complete/standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, 

"it doesn't seem to work the way I want it to" I mean when I close an app like the messenger I can still receive incoming call notifications from other people. because only when I open the app on my phone do I connect to socket.io and get other notifications and when i close the app the socket disconnect is automatically called

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen , You mean FCM is firebase notification?

Comment: Notifications systems like Web Push uses service workers, which are used to run background tasks and stay there even after you close the app. They are made this way so you can trigger some events without having the actual app displayed (like notifications, cron tasks, ...can't think of more examples). While this doesn't "fix" your problem, you can learn more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API

Comment: It's good to know more about this, I'll go check it out now, thanks @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In react native firebase there are two types of notifications `"background"` and `"foreground"`.

**Foreground Notifications:**

A foreground service performs some operation that is noticeable to the user. For example, an audio app would use a foreground service to play an audio track. Foreground services must display a [Notification](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications). Foreground services continue running even when the user isn't interacting with the app.

When you use a foreground service, you must display a notification so that users are actively aware that the service is running. This notification cannot be dismissed unless the service is either stopped or removed from the foreground.

**Background Notification:**

A background service performs an operation that isn't directly noticed by the user. For example, if an app used a service to compact its storage, that would usually be a background service.

> You want to follow there [Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification) to apply push notifications in react native.